# Solution to the Liouville-Gibbs equation

Tags: pde, reference-request, differential-equations

What would be the approach to numerically solve for $\rho(x,t)$ the following equation with some initial conditions
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}
+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial(\rho g_i)}{\partial x_i}\right)=0,$$
where $x = [x_1 ... x_n]^T$, $\dot{x}=g(x,t)$ and $g(x,t) = [g_1(x,t) ... g_n(x,t)]^T$ is given?

The problem is not complicated, but I'd like some reference book or example to have a look at.

Comment: The way you write it, the $x$ variables are functions of time -- they solve an ODE. Then what does it mean to take partial derivatives with regard to $x_i$?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the method of characteristics. Finite volume methods are desiged for similar problems